# How to get signed content from pkcs7 attached signature using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

using following code; when i tries to get access the signed from the PKCS7 attached  signature.

```
  cms = new CMSSignedData(envelopedData); //PKCS7 envelope
  String signedData = new String((byte[])cms.getSignedContent().getContent());
```

I got the output like this.

```
nº™(5Âš?¶ÁNšc«n‘¶˜Êõûøˆ‚<ùæB0¸ð¿ø"˜ZÊ×`—õWøž8¹¨c¼‘Ç{¥é×Æx¢ôãÕ›|?€çžÆ3ÔÜç&¦¤X„õ·3c'Gž\³Ö/€Á<ž²¬ÿµƒÉâw…«b›¤?¤­1®kB•ô?³Á­2€¦?r`!¦÷nt¯*Ÿ
```

Same thing works fine for detached signature. For attached signature, i used the following code.

```
CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);
```

Even. I tried all the charsets for the signedData String.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and resolved it. It was due to the double signing process.